# Close currently opened tab using Angular 6

Tags: angular

I want to close a currently opened tab when I click on a button using Angular 6. I have tried using window.close() function but it is returning a warning "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them.", How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: The message you are receiving is correct.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Open the window through JavaScript and then you can close it. I don't know what you're use case is, but maybe a dialog or some other form of popup would fit better.